# Image resize crash in share extention

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm trying to implement a share extension in my ios application. I want to share photos and before the app will send them to the backend I want to resize the photos.
I'm using this function:

```
+(UIImage*) resizedImage :(UIImage*) image andPreferredSize:(CGSize) size
{
    if(image.size.height > size.height && image.size.width > size.width)
    {
        float ratio1 = image.size.height/size.height;
        float ratio2 = image.size.width/size.width;
        float ratio3 = ratio1 < ratio2 ? ratio1 : ratio2;
        
        CGSize newSize =  CGSizeMake(image.size.width/ratio3 , image.size.height/ratio3);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        image = [[newImage retain] autorelease];
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();        
    }
    
    return  image;
}
```

If i share multiple photos(in a serial queue) in the second photo i get this msg error and crash:

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
```

The memory usage does not exceed 20 Mb. Any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: What `size` are you passing for `andPreferredSize` ?

Comment: and... is your goal to **grow** the image? or **shrink** it? and... are you expecting the output size to be in **pixels** or in **points**?

Comment: Consider using `UIImage imageByPreparingThumbnailOfSize:` instead writing your own method.

Comment: @HangarRash - `imageByPreparingThumbnailOfSize:` *might* be a good alternative, but the sizing appears to be ***very quirky*** (unless I'm completely mis-understanding what it is supposed to be doing).

Comment: @DonMag i want to resize from (width = 3024, height = 4032) to (width = 768, height = 1024)

Comment: @YosiFZ - this line: `image = [[newImage retain] autorelease];` is really out of place. Have you disabled **ARC** for some reason? If so, why?

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code I use to resize my images .it is in swift you can take clue from this.

```
func resize(targetSize: CGSize) -> Data {      
    var actualHeight = Float(self.size.height)
    var actualWidth = Float(self.size.width)
    let maxHeight: Float = Float(targetSize.width)
    let maxWidth: Float = Float(targetSize.height)
    var imgRatio: Float = actualWidth / actualHeight
    let maxRatio: Float = maxWidth / maxHeight
    let compressionQuality: Float = 0.5
    //50 percent compression
    if actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth {
        if imgRatio < maxRatio {
            //adjust width according to maxHeight
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight
            actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth
            actualHeight = maxHeight
        }
        else if imgRatio > maxRatio {
            //adjust height according to maxWidth
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth
            actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight
            actualWidth = maxWidth
        }
        else {
            actualHeight = maxHeight
            actualWidth = maxWidth
        }
    }
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: CGFloat(actualWidth), height: CGFloat(actualHeight))
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    self.draw(in: rect)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    let imageData = img?.jpegData(compressionQuality: CGFloat(compressionQuality)) ?? Data()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return imageData
    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

image resize with OC.

```
- (void)resizeImage:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIImage* originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"big_image"];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            [[self class] resizedImage:originalImage andPreferredSize:CGSizeMake(768, 1024)];
            NSLog(@"index:%d", i);
        }
    }
}

+ (UIImage *)resizedImage:(UIImage*)image andPreferredSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (size.width != 0 && size.height != 0 && image.size.height > size.height && image.size.width > size.width) {
        // 这里image创建的时候需要考虑屏幕倍数  iphone7,8是2，x,xs，11pro是3.
        float device_pixel = 2;
        
        float ratio1 = size.height / image.size.height / device_pixel;
        float ratio2 = size.width / image.size.width / device_pixel;
        float ratio3 = ratio1 < ratio2 ? ratio1 : ratio2;
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(image.size.width * ratio3, image.size.height * ratio3), NO, 0.0);
          
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width * ratio3, image.size.height * ratio3)];
        //   由于涉及到float运算，返回值的图片分辨率可能有+-1的差异。
        UIImage* resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return resizedImage;
    }
    return  image;
}
```